# Grid View convert to pdf using devexpress ASPXGridViewExporter tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

Is there any way I can convert an Asp.net grid view to PDF format, or any other format, using the Devexpress ASPXGridViewExporter tool without converting the existing gridview to Devexpress ASPXGridView?

Comment: You were able to solve it or not yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but for exporting you need to go through a round-about method.

First, you need to have the `datasourceID` which you are binding to your ASP gridview. You can follow the steps for export; The following code should be written on Export Button Click.

```
        ASPxGridView grd = new ASPxGridView(); //create instance of aspxgridview
        grd.AutoGenerateColumns = true; //this should be set true so that automatically data gets bind
        grd.ID = "Test"; //give any id
        grd.DataSource = objs; //Datasource Id - could be objectdatasource
        grd.KeyFieldName = "TestField";  //keyfield name in the datasource
        this.Controls.Add(grd);             
        grd.DataBind();

        ASPxGridViewExporter1.GridViewID = "Test";
        ASPxGridViewExporter1.WritePdfToResponse();
        this.Controls.Remove(grd); //would remove the temporarily created instance of devex grid
```